# Delete function in php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make a dynamic table with ajax/jquery.

other functions such as add, update are working but my delete function seem to be not working. I am digging into this problem but with no result.

Below is the snippet which fetches data from the database and form up a table.
Each row has update/delete buttons which lead into appropriate functions.

```html
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    { 
        $number = 1; 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        { 
            $data .= '<tr> 
                <td>'.$number.'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['Surname'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['Name'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['Address'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['Telephone'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['PurchaseDate'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['Model'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['SerialNumber'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['Notes'].'</td> 
                <td> 
                    <button onclick="GetUserDetails('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button> 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                    <button onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button> 
                </td> 
            </tr>'; 
            $number++; 
        } 
    }
```

here is my delete function it receives the id of the row from the other php where it loads table from database.

**Delete Function script**

```html
function DeleteUser(id) {
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure, do you really want to delete User?");
    if (conf == true) {
        $.post("ajax/deleteUser.php", {
                id: id
            },
            function (data, status) {
                // reload Users by using readRecords();
                readRecords();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**deletefunction php**

```html
<?php   
// check request   
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['id']) != "")   
{   
    // include Database connection file   
    include("db_connection.php");   

    // get user id   
    $client_id = $_POST['id'];   

    // delete User   
    $query = "DELETE FROM Clients WHERE id = '$client_id'";   
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($query)) {   
        exit(mysqli_error($result)); 
    }   
}   
?>
```

I even tried going into mysql instead of mysqli, and it somehow worked. I am kinda assuming that mysqli has different function than mysql? Well I heard mysql is deprecated but it seems I am doing wrong something here...

I am not good at programming, I am learning as it became my new hobby. Any tips would be thankful.

Comment: Try to change `if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['id']) != "")` to `if(isset($_POST['id'])) `

Comment: @RazibAlMamun Tried that before, didnt work. Thank you anyway for the tips

Comment: So the request makes it to `deletefunction.php` but the `mysql` query fails? You are correct, don't use `mysql_*` functions. This is open to SQL injections currently.

Comment: Does `db_connection.php` open a `mysqli` or `mysql_*` connection? The `mysqli_query` requires the connection string as its first parameter. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php. Also @RazibAlMamun is correct. `isset` will never return `''`, you probably could use `if(!empty(trim($_POST['id']))) {`.

Comment: Everything is on mysqli at the moment

Comment: Okay, then in that case change the `mysqli_query` call to use the connection. You also should enable error reporting and check your logs.

Comment: try to with this code : `var conf = confirm("Are you sure, do you really want to delete User?");
    if (conf == true) {  
  $.ajax({
   url: "ajax/deleteUser.php",
   type: "POST", 
   data: {id:id},
   contentType: false,
  }).done(function (data) {
      alert(data);
   readRecords();          
  }).fail(function (data) {
   console.log('failed');
  });
 }`

Comment: something is definitely wrong with my code, Razib's 2nd alert gives me empty alert and Chris85, I tried enabling error also shows nil. I thought maybe the page is not reloaded so i checked the database itself but query didnt work

Comment: Open the developer console. Does the request go out and come back? Also the PHP, as is, is still invalid. Fix the `mysqli_query` call.

Comment: see the answer posted by Pupil. You are missing connection parameter. The connection needs be of mysqli (not only query) and it needs to be provided as first parameter in query.  So, mysqli_connect and then mysqli_query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqli_*` is more object oriented and imporved version of MySQL.

You need to pass connection id to `mysqli_query()`

> mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode =
>   MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

So, the corrected code:

```
if (!$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
// Where $conn is the connection identifier.
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 0):

This query worked for me at last.

```html
    // delete User  
    $query = "DELETE FROM Clients WHERE id = '$client_id'";  
   if (!$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $query)) { 
        exit(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false))); 
    }
```